# Grabbing data from web service xsd:base64Binary field in Java

Tags: java, jaxb

I have a web service I am trying to call from Java.  The XSD for the service defines a field as an xsd:base64Binary.  I am using maven jaxb2 plugin to generate Java artifacts.  The field becomes a byte[] in the generated Java object.  The data that comes back in that field is either CSV or XML data depending on what is passed into the service.  SoapUI displays the data perfectly (not encoded).  Watching the wire with wireshark I can also see the non encoded data.  My question is, how do I grab this data as a string in Java?  I want to take this data and later write it into a file.

Response looks something like this:
Service Agreement,Interval Start Time,Interval End Time,Quantity,Unit of Measure .... etc.

Relevant bit of XSD:

Relevant bit of generated java:
protected byte[] greenDoc;

In my client java code I have been trying every possible combination of new String(byte[]), new String(byte[], charset), Base64 decoding, etc. and I just cannot seem to get the data correctly.  I know it is not a limitation of the web service because like I said SoapUI can display the data perfectly.

Any pointers on how the client code can take the byte array and convert to string?  Thanks!

Comment: Should add that I was sniffing the traffic called from my java code, so I know it is calling the web service correctly and the correct data is coming back.  I just cannot seem to get string data that is decoded correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Programmatically, you can use [DatatypeConverter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter.html#printBase64Binary(byte[]))

Comment: Thanks Steve, I actually forgot to mention that I had used DatatypeConverter (printBase64Binary method) and had some luck, but oddly, all special characters were stripped from the data.  No spaces, commas, anything like that.  Any ideas?

Comment: Interesting, I've never experienced that before using DatatypeConverter. BTW, if you're using java1.8 you can also try java.util.Base64.  If you post an example Base64 encoded String, I can take a look and see why DatatypeConverter is not working.